# Autocomplete doesn't work inside ui repeat

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem with p:autocomplete element. It is nested inside double ui:repeat, and it doesn't respond. If I put it out of second ui:repeat and place it in the first repeat or out of both repeats, autocomplete works normally. Does anybody have a clue what could be a problem?

Comment: Please provide your code, the jsp page and the managed bean.

Comment: What JSF impl/version are you using? [Please remember to mention that in every JSF question](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info). For instance, older Mojarra versions have partial state management problems during handling of ajax requests coming from nested `<ui:repeat>`. Solution is easy: upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code.

```
          <ui:repeat id="joinConditionPart"
            value="#{join.joinParts}" var="joinPart" varStatus="conditionIndex" >
          <div class="line-group" >
            <p:outputLabel value="ON" rendered="#{conditionIndex.index == 0}"
             styleClass="join-left" />
            <p:outputLabel value="AND" rendered="#{conditionIndex.index != 0}"
            styleClass="join-left" />
            <p:autoComplete id="leftJoinPart"
               converter="stringConverter"
               completeMethod="#{editRuleBBean.autocomplete()}"
               dropdown="true"
               disabled="#{editRuleBBean.rule.type == 'ANALYSIS' and
               editRuleBBean.rule.id != null}">

            </p:autoComplete>
            <span class="text join-middle">=</span>

            <p:autoComplete id="rightJoinPart"
              rendered="true"
              value="#{joinPart.rightPart}" 
              completeMethod="#{editRuleBBean.autocomplete()}"
              converter="stringConverter"
              dropdown="true"
               >
              </p:autoComplete>
```

Bean works fine.

Comment: that is the nested ui:repeat.